# How to unit test old legacy application

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I was assigned to old web applicaton(JSF 1.2 + Eclipselink), there is no middleware like EJB or Spring and service layer of application is composed of POJO that directly calls EntityManager. Structure of the code is like this SomeBean(backing bean) -> SomeServices(here is mix of business logic and data access code), no seperate DAO layer. The code on service classes usually looks like this(here very simplified):

```
 public void someMethod(SomeEntity someEntity, ....) throws SomeServiceExeption {
    try{
        entitiyManager.getTransaction.begin();
        //lotOfLogicHereAndCallingSomeOtherPrivateMethods
        entitiyManager.getTransaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("");
            if(entitiyManager.getTransaction..isActive()){
                entitiyManager.getTransaction.rollback();
            }
        throw new SomeServiceExeption(e);
    }
}
```

This application has only few tests, that were testing almost nothing, so I am trying to cover as much code as possible with unit tests(there will be some changes commintg into  application that will require a lot of changes in legacy code which is not covered by tests). My question is how would you unit test code like this. I have three ideas:

1. Refactor to tests. I could introduce DAO layer and put all
   entityManager calls there. But refactoring without tests is allways
   problem.
2. Mock EntityManager. I tried this several times with EasyMock, it works
   and helps me to at least have some code coverage of code that
   requires changes, but is probably not good style, as you should not
   mock api that does not belong to you. Also to prepare EntityManager mocks requires a lot    of time and code
3. Instead of unit testing, do integration testing with hsqldb or h2
   and some dummy test data. Well this would require probably most of
   the work and tests would be slow. Also I want to cover mostly
   bussiness logic, not data access.

Comment: If you haven't already got it, first go buy [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052)

Comment: Thanks, I will read it, it looks very promising.

Comment: As a comment on option 3: In memory databases like h2 are generally 'fast', but you need to provide some test data. If you already have this data in some other database, you could possibly use that or test against this database. Execution would be slow at first, but it would jump start the refactor and write unit tests process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably first add some integration tests and get coverage on the parts you want to refactor. Then, you can go on refactoring to more isolated units that are individually testable. If refactored correctly, you can then unit test your business logic seperately from the storage.

It's always a good idea to have some integration tests, so that would be a good place to start.

In any case, I wouldn't refactor code that's not covered by any tests.